# I don't understand how to correct this

Tags: javascript, html, css, queryselector

Hey I'm a new coder and I'm using freecode camp to learn js. I'm currently on the calorie counter exercise and I'm duplicating the code in VsCode. I just added an addEntry button to the js using a query selector and I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'querySelectorAll')
> at addEntry - filepath calorie counter.js 21

I'm a complete noob and I don't know what to search for.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="device=device-width, initial-scale= 1.0" />\
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\babat\OneDrive\Desktop\Vs Code Projects\JsApps\Calorie Counter.css" />
        <title>Calorie Counter</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <h1>Calorie Counter</h1>
            <div class="container">
                <form id="calorie-counter">
                    <label for="budget">Budget</label>
                    <input id="budget" type="number" min="0" placeholder="Daily Calorie Counter" required />
                    <fieldset class="breakfast">
                        <legend>Breakfast</legend>
                        <div class="input-container"></div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset id="lunch">
                        <legend>Lunch</legend>
                        <div class="input-container"></div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset id="dinner">
                        <legend>Dinner</legend>
                        <div class="input-container"></div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset id="snacks">
                        <legend>Snacks</legend>
                        <div class="input-container"></div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset id="exercise">
                        <legend>Exercise</legend>
                        <div class="input-container"></div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <span>
                            <label for="entry-dropdown">Add food or exercise</label>
                            <select id="entry-dropdown" name="options">
                                <option value="breakfast" selected>Breakfast</option>
                                <option value="lunch">Lunch</option>
                                <option value="dinner">Dinner</option>
                                <option value="snacks">Snacks</option>
                                <option value="exercise">Exercise</option>
                            </select>
                            <button id="add-entry" type="button">Add Entry</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit">Calculate Remaining Calories</button>
                        <button id="clear" type="button">Clear</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div id="output" class="output hide"></div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <script src="C:\Users\babat\OneDrive\Desktop\Vs Code Projects\JsApps\Calorie Counter.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
:root {
    --light-grey: #f5f6f7;
    --dark-blue: #0a0a23;
    --fcc-blue: #1b1b32;
    --light-yellow: #fecc4c;
    --dark-yellow: #feac32;
    --light-pink: #ffadad;
    --dark-red: #850000;
    --light-green: #acd157;
  }
  
  body {
    font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: var(--fcc-blue);
    color: var(--light-grey);
  }
  
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 680px;
  }
  
  h1,
  .container,
  .output {
    margin: 20px auto;
  }
  
  label,
  legend {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .input-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  button {
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: var(--light-yellow);
    border: 2px solid var(--dark-yellow);
  }
  
  .clear {
    background-color: var(--light-pink);
    color: var(--dark-red);
    border-color: var(--dark-red);
  }
  
  button,
  input,
  select {
    min-height: 24px;
    color: var(--dark-blue);
  }
  
  fieldset,
  label,
  button,
  input,
  select {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .output {
    border: 2px solid var(--light-grey);
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .output span {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  
  .surplus {
    color: var(--light-green);
  }
  
  .deficit {
    color: var(--light-pink);
  }
```

java:

```
const calorieCounter = document.getElementById('calorie-counter');
const budgetNumberInput = document.getElementById('budget');
const entryDropdown = document.getElementById('entry-dropdown');
const addEntryButton = document.getElementById('add-entry');
const clearButton = document.getElementById('clear');
const output = document.getElementById('output');
let isError = false;

function cleanInputString(str) {
  const regex = /[+-\s]/g;
  return str.replace(regex, '');
}

function isInvalidInput(str) {
  const regex = /\d+e\d+/i;
  return str.match(regex);
}

function addEntry() {
  const targetInputContainer = document.querySelector(`#${entryDropdown.value} .input-container`);
  const entryNumber = targetInputContainer.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]').length + 1;
  const HTMLString = `
  <label for="${entryDropdown.value}-${entryNumber}-name">Entry ${entryNumber} Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="${entryDropdown.value}-${entryNumber}-name" placeholder="Name" />
  <label for="${entryDropdown.value}-${entryNumber}-calories">Entry ${entryNumber} Calories</label>
  <input
    type="number"
    min="0"
    id="${entryDropdown.value}-${entryNumber}-calories"
    placeholder="Calories"
  />`;
  targetInputContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', HTMLString);
}



addEntryButton.addEventListener("click", addEntry);
```

The code works in the preview window of the freecode camp app but when I run it in visual studio code, it doesn't work and throws the error. I tried copying and pasting the code straight from the app into vs code but I still get the error.

Comment: suggests `targetInputContainer` is null

Comment: In VS Code, how and where did you add the Javascript? Directly into the html using a `<script>` tag or with a `.js` file? And, at the start or end inside `<body>` element? Depending on when the JS is being parsed, the `.input-container` element might not exist yet, therefore the variable `targetInputContainer` is most probably null.

Comment: console.log is a useful debugging tool. As others have said you will likely find targetInputContainer is null, and that is very possibly because the JS code is running before the HTML is fully loaded. Make sure for example, that the JS is after the HTML or is run on loading complete.

Comment: there is no  id="breakfast" but  class="breakfast"

Comment: Change `class="breakfast"` to `id="breakfast"` like all the other field sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTMl you added a class="breakfast" on the first fieldset element

```
 <fieldset class="breakfast">
        <legend>Breakfast</legend>
        <div class="input-container"></div>
  </fieldset>
```

where as in your javascript code you're trying to retrieve it by the id, `targetInputContainer` is null as a result and this is the cause of the error `Cannot read properties of null`

```
  const targetInputContainer = document.querySelector(`#${entryDropdown.value} .input-container`);
```

The solution is to change your the class="breakfast" to id="breakfast" in your html

```
<fieldset id="breakfast">
        <legend>Breakfast</legend>
        <div class="input-container"></div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: made the suggested changes and everything works fine. Thanks Barmar and Victoria Udechuckwu.